# Data set Transformation for Power BI

Tags: excel, csv, powerbi, powerquery, data-transform

Actually i'm working on Power BI to make an analysis of authors publications numbers and trends.
I have the data set shown in the image below.
A column of authors and and another for their IDs
in each cell, i'ev multiple authors at once, the same for their IDs
so my question
Is there a way to match each author with it's ID so i can proceed my analysis.

Thank you so much

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you chose to provide your data as a screenshot, which cannot be copy/pasted into a table, I had to make up my own.

- split each column into a list
- combine the two lists into a table

***Source***
[image]

***M Code** (Transform=>Home=>Advanced Editor)*

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords(
        {[Authors="Author A, Author B", #"Author(s) ID"="12345;67890;"],
         [Authors="Author C,Author D,Author E", #"Author(s) ID"="444123;789012;66666;"],
         [Authors="Author X, Author Y, Author Z, Author P", #"Author(s) ID"="1111;2222;3333;4444;"]}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Authors", type text},{"Author(s) ID", type text}}),

//split each column into a List; trim the entries
    authors = List.Combine(List.Transform(#"Changed Type"[Authors], each Text.Split(Text.Trim(_),","))),
    IDs = List.Combine(List.Transform(#"Changed Type"[#"Author(s) ID"], each Text.Split(Text.Trim(_,";"),";"))),

//create new table
    result = Table.FromColumns({authors,IDs},
                type table[Authors=text, #"Author(s) ID"=text])
in
    result
```

***Result***
[image]

Comment: First of all i would like to thank you for your precious help 
(Sorry for not uploading the file for confidentiality reasons) 
i would like to ask if i'ev to declare each row in the M code 
like this way 
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords(
        {[Authors="Author A, Author B", #"Author(s) ID"="12345;67890;"], 


Or if there's a way to define all the column at once because i have 4010 row

Comment: @MohamedLiesTOUALBIA I suppose typing a table in manually is one way of doing it.  Is that what you are doing now?  I only did it that way because I had to make something up, since you did not provide any data.  But PQ has many connectors. I suggest you input your data into the program using whatever method you are using now.

Comment: well i'm a csv file from a database
that's why i asked about how to define the table instead of doing it row by row 
Anyway i guess i should search about how to do it 
the answer was exactly what i needed thank you guys

Comment: @MohamedLiesTOUALBIA If your data is coming from a CSV file, your first few lines of code probably look like `Source=Csv.Document(File.Contents("full path"), ...  ` followed by `#"Promoted Headers = "` and then `#"Changed Type=`.  So you should be able to just replace my `Source=` with your first **two** lines of code.  So long as your column names are the same as what I show, that should do the job for you.

Comment: i wish i could, each time i try to cast a vote i get this message "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."